# xpath is not working as expected in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have following xml

```
<myRequest>
    <id>123456789</id>
</myRequest>
```

I have the following xslt not working to get the same as output

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="myRequest">
        <myRequest>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="id"/>
        </myRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <customerId>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </customerId>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

working xslt

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="myRequest">
        <myRequest>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//id"/>
        </myRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <customerId>
            <xsl:value-of select="//id"/>
        </customerId>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I put current() in the XWatch,it is also not showing any thing when debug pointer is in

```
<xsl:template match="myRequest">
            <myRequest>
..........................
```

Why  i need to use **//** here ?Because **id** element is directly under  **myRequest**.I really got confused using **//** here?

Without using **//** also we need to get the output.

What the mistake i am doing here ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first template needs to look like this...

```
<xsl:template match="id">
    <customerId>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </customerId>
</xsl:template>
```

The expression in the `xsl:value-of` will be relative to the current node you are on (the `id`) node, so by doing `<xsl:value-of select="id" />` you are looking for a node called `id` that is a child of the current `id` element. Doing `.` gets the value of the current node.

Doing `//id` works because when you start the expression with `/` it will be relative to the top-level document node, and doing `//` will then search for the first `id` anywhere in the document.

Note, consider building your XSLT upon the XSLT identity template, as that will make it much more generic, and able to change the `id` element anywhere in the document.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <customerId>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </customerId>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ya it is working fine.Thank u so much.But when i use <xsl:template match="/"> instead of <xsl:template match="myRequest">,then not working .What is the reason?

Comment: `/` is used for match the top-level document node, which is the parent of `myRequest`. So if you then do `<xsl:apply-templates select="id" />` it is assuming that `id` is the root element. You would need to do `<xsl:apply-templates select="myRequest/id" />`